# random graph on the reals

Tags: random-graphs, infinitary-combinatorics

Is there a unique graph $G$ such that a random graph with vertex set $\mathbb{R}$ and a half chance of any two vertices being connected is isomorphic to $G$ with probability $1$?

I am curious about whether there is an uncountable version of the Rado graph, and the question is equivalent to asking whether there is a graph with vertex set $\mathbb{R}$ that contains as induced subgraphs all other graphs with vertex sets of cardinality up to that of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'half chance of any two vertices being connected'?  I don't immediately see the equivalency you're talking about, and maybe fleshing that out would help?

Comment: I am wondering what the notion of a *graph isomorphism* applies to random graphs -- you only know the number of vertices, not the edges?